# Trying to call a method in a struct from inside my View struct

Tags: swift, swiftui, struct

I have a struct and I am using as a view

```
struct CritterView: View {

@Binding var critterViewIsShowing:Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        CritterViewHeader(critterViewIsShowing: $critterViewIsShowing)
        
    }
    
    // this works
    // let _ = CritterData().getCritterData()
    
// this does not work
    let _ = print(Ziggy)
    let _ = CritterData().addCritter(critter: Ziggy)
    
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access a function inside another struct

```
struct CritterData{
// Assignment 3
var crittersArray: [Critter] = []

mutating func addCritter(critter:Critter){
    
    print(critter.name)
//        crittersArray.append(critter)
}

func getCritterData(){
   print("This is critter data")
}

}
```

I can call the getCritterData method, but when I try to call the addCritter and pass a Critter to add to the array within the struct I get this error:

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
```

I'm just trying to understand the error and how to fix it.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are try to do here, but I would say that you should look into making a view model for your "CritterView" that is an Observable object and modify your "CritterData" in the view model.

Comment: try var _ = CritterData().addCritter(critter: Ziggy)

Comment: You use the `body` of your view to define your UI, you do not use it to execute swift code like inn some normal function or computed property. So the error you get is because you are not using SwiftUI as you should.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something that can fire an action, e.g. a Button:

```
struct CritterView: View {

    @Binding var critterViewIsShowing: Bool

    @Binding var critterData: CritterData

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            CritterViewHeader(critterViewIsShowing: $critterViewIsShowing)
            Button("Add Ziggy") {
                critterData.addCritter(critter: Critter.ziggy)
            }
        }
    }
```